# On Linux can I keep a program running in background even after I disconnect?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

If I'm logged into a remote Linux machine, I know I can suspend a process (cntr-z) and move it to the background (bg 1) but if I disconnect from the machine, the process stops.

Is there a way I can leave it in the background and have it there when I log back in? This is a very long running process.

On Ubuntu, logged in via SSH.

Answer (score 10):

This is because your program need terminal to run, you can use [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) to create a virtual terminal so that the program will continue to run even after you disconnect.
just run `screen your_program_name`, you can close screen with `crtl-a-d` then reopen it later with `screen -rx`

Comment: Wish I could accept your answer but I posted w/o logging in and now can't actually claim the question. =x But thank you, works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

Less flexible than screen are `nohup` and `disown`.

`nohup` is a program, and you have to start the long running jub with it like this:

```
$ nohup longjob --options-for-longjob
```

it will cause your long job to run in the background and *not attached to any terminal* (which means that you won't get any output from it on the screen and won't be able to direct input to it from the keyboard)

`disown` is a bash builtin that can disconnect a long running job *after* you've started it. My bash man page says

> disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]
>                 Without options, each jobspec  is  removed  from  the  table  of
>                 active  jobs.   If  the  -h option is given, each jobspec is not
>                 removed from the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent
>                 to  the  job  if  the shell receives a SIGHUP.  If no jobspec is
>                 present, and neither the -a nor the -r option is  supplied,  the
>                 current  job  is used.  If no jobspec is supplied, the -a option
>                 means to remove or mark all jobs; the -r option without  a  job-
>                 spec  argument  restricts operation to running jobs.  The return
>                 value is 0 unless a jobspec does not specify a valid job.